# How to sort a matrix based on one index I have?

Tags: matlab

```
t = [ 4 2
      2 6
      6 9];
c = [ 2
      3
      1];
```

Now, I want to arrange `t` according to `c` index; I need to get `t` new sorted based on `c`:

```
t = [ 2 6
      4 2
      6 9];
```

How to sort a matrix based on one index I have?

Here is what I tried:

```
h = cell(1,1);
h{1,1} = t;
h{1,1}(c)
```

Comment: Are you assuming that row indexes begin from bottom?

Comment: no
t(c,:) gives me the answer

Comment: `t(c,:)` gives you `[2 6;6 9;4 2]` that is different than what you want.

Answer (score 0):

this code makes use of the key:value mapping available in matlab. You could incorporate this into a function and tweak it for any arbitrary matrix `t` and `c` which I've relabeled `keySet`

```
t = [ 4 2;2 6; 6 9]; % original matrix
keySet = [ 2 3 1]; % original c indexing vector

valueSet= cell(1,size(t,1)); % create a cell matrix to hold the row elements of t
for i =1:size(t,1)
    valueSet{1,i} = t(i,:); % insert row elements into cell array
end
mapObj = containers.Map(keySet,valueSet); % map the keys to the values

keySet = sort(keySet,'descend'); % reorder the keys
for j=1:size(keySet,2)
    t(j,:) = mapObj(keySet(1,j)); % rebuild matrix t with new order
end
```

Comment: Thank you, we simply can use t(c,:)

Comment: yep. much simpler than my method